# Position UILabel at a slant or angle

Tags: ios, uilabel

I'm writing iOS5 app.

I'm using UILabel to show the text over an image. By default UILabel will be horizontal or vertical.

But I want to place the label with some angle (say 10 degrees).
Is it possible with UILabel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply some rotation to it's transform

```
label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(10 * M_PI/180);
```

The `angle` argument is expected in radians

Comment: what about the blurriness? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492367/how-do-i-achieve-a-clearly-rendered-rotated-uilabel