# How do I achieve a clearly rendered rotated UILabel?

Tags: ios, core-animation, uilabel

I am trying to display rotated text. The UILabel is added as a subview on a UIImageView. The UIImageView has a transform created via say CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/4.0). The text of the UILabel renders fairly blurry cf. the title label (in the screenshot, the blue background 'What's ...').

Do you know how I can manage to make the rotated text render clearly?

I've already tried using an integral-based frame (which matters little since it'll be rotated), a non-clear background color, and setting the label to opaque=YES.  Still blurry.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you using the `shouldRasterize` property on your label’s layer, or that of its superview? That looks blurry enough to be an issue with an incorrect `rasterizationScale`.

Comment: Nope! I tried on both to no avail as well...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your label is rendered in half pixel either in the origin of the frame or the rotation. Check the frame origin after rotation, or try to rotate it by M_PI/4.1 (4.2, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5 - even test values like 4.05 4.15..) until it renders normally. Also check the frame of the UILabel in the UIImageView, could be added at half pixel origin for ex. {0.5, 0.5} or something..

Comment: I tried forcing the UIImageView and the UILabel to use integral coordinates by updating their frames every second. Still blurry! :(

Comment: Their coordinates change after rotation, make sure that it's not blurry when not rotated first and then rotate it. By the way if you are setting the center property of the label or the uiimageview could be a problem, try to replace setting the center with setting the whole frame...

Comment: Yeah it was after rotation. What's this about setting center causing problems? I tried using just frame and didn't get any difference.

Comment: This with the center happens to me very often on an UILabel and I am trying to avoid it.. It takes time sometimes to adjust it to render normally it's a pain..

Comment: for me below line is causing the issue. It might helps for any one. View.Layer.ShouldRasterize = true; . After removed this line font works perfectly.